# PyQGIS Plugin: After setting Layer and Field in combobox, how to refer to them in the processing code?

Tags: pyqgis

I have created multiple comboboxes, two layer comboboxes and two field comboboxes. However, I dont understand, how I can now refer to the selections in the processing code?
[image]
In the Image you find on the left the code and on the right the created comboboxes. How do I now refer to the selections in my processing code?

```
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = CopyPasteDialog()

            #comboBox_source = self.dlg.comboBox_source
            #comboBox_field_source = self.dlg.comboBox_field_source
            
            self.dlg.comboBox_source.layerChanged.connect(self.populate_comboBox_field)
            self.dlg.comboBox_target.layerChanged.connect(self.populate_comboBox_field_target)

        self.dlg.comboBox_source.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer)
        self.populate_comboBox_field()

        self.dlg.comboBox_target.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer)
        self.populate_comboBox_field_target()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this myself:

```
# QgsMapLayerComboBox
            source_layer_name = self.dlg.comboBox_source.currentLayer().name()
            target_layer_name = self.dlg.comboBox_target.currentLayer().name()
# QComboBox
            source_field_name = self.dlg.comboBox_field_source.currentText()
            target_field_name = self.dlg.comboBox_field_target.currentText()
```

As the layer comboboxes are widgets form Qgs you refer to them with 'currentLayer()' method and you will actually get a Qgs vector layer. Therefore, to get just the name of the layer, you call the name() method.
The field boxes are in my case normal qt-comboboxes, so you refer to their text with the currentText() method.